# Arch Linux Issue after the upgrade, system timers ignoring the time specified to execute a service file

Tags: systemd, archlinux

I have various system timer files, each timer file should execute the specified service file at the time of the day which is specified in the timer file. It was all working as it should be before I upgraded the arch linux using the command: 
sudo pacman -Syu

Note: I am using the arch linux on Raspberry pi 3

Problem after upgrading:

One of the timer files we have is the daily_reboot.timer. This file should execute the daily_reboot.service file everyday at 1 am. So the system should reboot every night at 1 am because this timer file should execute the service file only at 1 am everyday.
But for some reason, the system keeps rebooting and rebooting for whole time. Looking at logs and observing the pattern, I found that all the timer files are getting executed every time the system boots and the timer files are calling the service file every time, seems like timer files are ignoring the line which says the time (1 am in case of daily reboot) and service files get executed by ignoring the time specification in the timer file.
This leads to constant rebooting of system because the daily reboot timer keeps calling the service file, which reboots the system and same thing repeats again.

If I disable the daily reboot timer, the system stops rebooting. 
sudo systemctl disable daily_reboot.timer 
This command deletes the symbolic link of that timer, and hence system does not see the daily reboot timer then.

But for our device, we need to have a daily reboot at 1 am everyday. This is necessary for my project. Can anyone help me here or did anyone experience this issue before ??

[service file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMXWu.png)

[timer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEp2o.png)

Comment: Note that this should probably be tagged archlinux-arm

Comment: The Persistent=false option should stop this from happening. Strange